# send data as the header in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http-headers

I want to send data as header in my post request

I am using the following code and it work fine.

```
  File file = File("my file");
    var request =
            http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse("https://myhost.com"));
        request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            'media', file.readAsBytesSync(),
            filename: file.path.split("/").last));
    
        String test = "hi";
    
        Map<String, String> header = {};
        header = {'tocken': '12345', 'note': "hi"};
    
        request.headers.addAll(header);
    
        var response = await request.send();
```

but when I want to send the test value to the header (as the bellow code) it does not send the request. How may I fix this and what is wrong?

```
header = {'tocken': '12345', 'note': test};
```

Comment: what error do you get

Comment: There isn't any error. Actually I don't get the request in my nodejs server.